# The connection string for a local SQL 2012 Express Server Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

So I've been wanting to learn a little more about SQL but I'm having some trouble connecting to a local SQL server database in the ASP.NET project I'm working on. Though I'm able to connect using Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio, I just can't get the connection string right. I've been looking at connectionstrings.com but I get exceptions when using alot of the keywords it suggests (server, initial catalog, database, etc.).

*Edit - Added Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StarterSite" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StarterSite.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <add name="AdventureWorks" connectionString="Data Source=ROBERT-PC;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=True" />
    <add name="DefaultConnnection" connectionString="Data Source=ROBERT-PC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234.0.0" newVersion="1.5.2.14234.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.data>        
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data></configuration>
```

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: Post your config file with your connection string please

Comment: <add name="AdventureWorks" connectionString="Data Source=ROBERT-PC;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=True" /> This is the connection string that Visual Studio shows me and yes I've been attempting to modify it with the link you posted but have yet to get anything other than a "Keyword not supported" exception.

Answer (score 2):

Generally visual studio per default use "defaultConnectionString" you may try this

```
<add name="DefaultConnnection"
  connectionString="Data Source=YOURMACHINE\YOUR_SQLEXPRESS_INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Obviously it will change if you are using EF it could be little bit different

Comment: The local instance uses Windows Authentication btw, would I need to substitute the Username and Password properties for something else?